# xlib (или gtk). C++. Выделить окно

Tags: c++, gtk, xlib

Мое приложение шарит часть рабочего стола с окном какого-либо приложения. Когда эту шару кто-то просматривает, то на машине, на которой запущено приложение, нужно как-то выделить окно расшаренного приложения. Сейчас я рисую вокруг него рамку с помощью `GtkWidget`. Но с этой рамкой есть много проблем особенно на разных DE (убрать рамку если приложение свернули или перекрыли, изменить размер рамки при изменеии размеров окна и т.п.). Поэтому я хочу найти вариант как-то по другому выделить окно. Вопрос, можно ли используя xlib или gtk как-нибудь выделить окно (например, аналог функции [FlashWindowEx](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-flashwindowex)
 для Windows, или может как-то можно поменять цвет рамки окна)?